# Adding the styles of multiple classes using SCSS?

Tags: css, sass

I want to include the styles of four classes in one. And add some more style. I am not too sure about SCSS. Is this the right way to do it?

```
.react-datagrid {
  @extend .table;
  @extend .table-striped;
  @extend .table-bordered;
  @extend .table-condensed;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is, as you can see in this jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0nptv6sf/1/

HTML :

```
<div class="react-datagrid">test</div>
```

SCSS :

```
.table {
  color: red;
}

.table-striped {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.table-bordered {
  background-color: black;
}

.table-condensed {
  padding: 10px;
}

.react-datagrid {
  @extend .table;
  @extend .table-striped;
  @extend .table-bordered;
  @extend .table-condensed;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: thanks for fiddling it out. not sure about scss. was thinking of some other keyword other than extend.

Answer (score 0):

#Another concept here

#single css
.table {
color: red;
}

```
.table-striped {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.table-bordered {
  background-color: black;
}

.table-condensed {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

for extend multiple class overwrite or extend

```
.element {
   @xtend .table; 
   @extend .table-striped;
   @extend .table-bordered;
   @extend .table-condensed;
}
```

it's better than prev extend

```
.element {
    @extend #{'.table', '.table-striped', '.table-bordered','.table- 
              condensed',....'.class-n'};
    // ohters css here
}
```

It's simple and works fine, just u add inside the second curly brasses.

===Thank you===